# How to set up notifications for new stories/bugs created in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, notifications

I am trying to create new subscription notification that informs me when anyone creates a new user story or bug in my teams area path. However, with what I set up I am getting a ton more emails than I expected - including status changes, iteration path changes, notifications of stories that are connected to a different area path in the same overall team.

Here is the filter criteria I have entered:
work item type equals user story
or work item type equals bug
and area path equals (team specific path)
and state changes to new